# jQuery Syntax Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-error

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#input_6_4\\.3_label").html("City/Borough");
    $("#input_6_8\\.3_label").html("City/Borough");

    $("#gform_next_button_6_42").click(function(){
        alert("hi");

    )};
});
```

Firebug keeps spitting out a syntax error with the above code with the offender being these characters:

```
)};
```

Any ideas at what's wrong because the code seems good to me?

Comment: Hmm. Someone seems to be wanting to silently make a point. I think you received a down-vote for not phrasing the title as a question...

Comment: Also, if PaulPRO answered your question, don't forget to mark it as so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are in the wrong order:

```
)};
```

Should be:

```
});
```

Comment: Cant believe I missed that, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

it should be `});`, you close your arguments list before closing the function body.